# How to add two NSString objetcs?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, variable-assignment

I i have a problem with simple assignment of NSStrings. My code looks like this:

```
NSString * info;
info=[newLocation description];   
NSString * bodyMessage =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tralalla %@", info];
```

when am just printing the value of "info" everything goes ok, but in here in the last line i have an error ;/ anyone knows how could i solve it ?

Comment: Copy&Paste error? There is a semicolon missing after the declaration of `info`.

Comment: How does newLocation look like? May be bodyMessage is already defined?

Comment: Could you correct the sample to let the error appear to everyone, please?

Comment: my bad with semiclone but only in here. debuging and building is ok. during the app is working my app is crashing in the 3rd line of that code ... i check id using NSLOG..

Comment: Please tell us what the error is.  Nobody here can read your mind.

Comment: i think that the problem here is to add two NSString and dunno have to do it

Comment: i dont know the content of the error.. its like theard 1  and app paused

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the "thread 1" part of the screen. (Or since you have low reputation, upload the screenshot to somewhere and link to it instead)

Answer (score 2):

Your comment suggests you have a breakpoint on that line:

[image: breakpoint]

Drag the little blue arrow on the left until it turns into a cloud of smoke, then release.

Or go to that line and press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>\</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's wrong with your code, but try replacing the third line with

```
NSString *bodyMessage = [@"tralalla " stringByAppendingString:info];
```

**Edit:** And make sure you put the semicolon after the first line, as Dirk said...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
NSString * bodyMessage =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"tralalla", info];
```

Hope this helps!